# How do I pass a string within a string within a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript playAudio() function which expects a string parameter. I can't seem to figure out how to pass a string value as a parameter for this function without breaking out of the string.

```
htmlString = "<button class='button-icon' value='PLAY' onclick='playAudio()'></button>";
```

I want to pass the string "SP00005" as a parameter. However I am unable to use inverted commas or apostrophes as these have already been used for the more outer part of my htmlString.

I even tried breaking up formation of htmlString into various steps as illustrated below:

```
htmlString = "";
htmlString += "<button class='button-icon' value='PLAY' onclick='playAudio(";
htmlString += "SP00005";
htmlString += ")'></button>";
```

So my question to you is: how do I pass a string within a string which itself is in a string?

Comment: htmlString = "<button class='button-icon' value='PLAY' onclick='playAudio(\"more strings \")'></button>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to escape the `"`.

```
htmlString = "<button class='button-icon' value='PLAY' onclick='playAudio(\"foo\")'></button>";
```

The better option is to select the button with javascript, add an eventListener and don't bother about inline js

```
<button id="fooBtn" class='button-icon' value='PLAY'></button>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('fooBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    playAudio("SP00005");
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Escaping did the trick! An event listener wasn't suitable because the page is dynamic and adds different buttons according to the content loaded by the database. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can escape " with `\"'`

Example test = `"Hello, I am \"Steve\""`

which resolves to: Hello, I am "Steve"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this way, using \" inside playAudio():

```
htmlString = "";
htmlString += "<button class='button-icon' value='PLAY' onclick='playAudio(\"";
htmlString += "SP00005";
htmlString += "\")'></button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use back ticks. This will allow you to build the string however you want without escape characters

```
var string = `<button class='button-icon' value='PLAY' onclick='playAudio('SP00005')'></button>`;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Starting with es6, no IE support, but a good way of doing this nowadays

Comment: Thanks for that caveat baao !

Comment: I hate to say it, I'm using template strings all the time.. But everything new breaks IE... :)